# Open extension page in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make an extension that on click opens a tab and goes to a page.  The only thing I can make it do so far is open a tab and give me this error:

> No webpage was found for the web address:
>   chrome-extension://hgjkkhjinhilcehaaldcnopaefinlfif/https://www.google.com/

Here is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "New App",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
   "manifest_version": 2,     
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

Here is background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
    (function(tab) 
        {chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('https://www.google.com/')}, function(tab) {})
        }                                    
    )
```

Comment: Where did you get this incorrect manifest code? I've seen the mistake before: `background_page` is a property of the root element, not of `browser_action`. Besides, `background_page` has been replaced with `"background"`, see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html.

Comment: Thanks, I've made some progress.  I can open a tab now!

[code]
{
  "name": "New App",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "background": "background.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}[/code]



[code]chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('page.html')}, function(tab) {
  });
});[/code]

Comment: Here's Google's response though:

<pre>
No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-extension://hgjkkhjinhilcehaaldcnopaefinlfif/page.html
<code>

Please excuse my ignorance with code blocks on this site.
Also, how do I post code in the comments?  [code] doesn't work here.

Comment: `test`

@Rob

    <pre>test<code>

Comment: Update your question, and insert the code. Select it and press Ctrl+K, then each line will be prefixed with four spaces (or, if you're selecting only a part of a line, surrounded in backticks). This marks a code block. Regarding Not found: Are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: Is the URL **really** set to `https://google.com/`? If yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9586857.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i load a webpage in a popup chrome extension without iframe and using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585163/how-i-load-a-webpage-in-a-popup-chrome-extension-without-iframe-and-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

What I was trying to do was open a new tab and go to a website in the browser action.  Here is the answer:

Manifest.json

```
{ "name": "Funny Pictures",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "description": "Rick Roll all your friends!",
  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "funnyface.png"
  },
  "icons": {
            "48": "funnyface.png"
            },
    "background":{
                    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";

    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

I swear I tried this previously, but that's how it goes I guess.