# Force HTTP. not HTTPS chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried Requestly chrome extension to make https:// requests into http:// for www.twitch.tv, I have also tried webRequest API..

Both of these give the Chrome error page "Too many redirects"

I have searched in Chrome HSTS for twitch.tv, but it was not even set.

I have tried to telnet port 80 of www.twitch.tv so it should be serving unsecure...

Does anybody have a working solution for forcing a new page into HTTP (not HTTPS) via a Chrome Extension, specifically www.twitch.tv?

The reason for all this is i want to implement HTML5 into Twitch.tv, but CSP is so strict that i can't load the video stream from HTTP only CDN via hls.js.... (meanwhile for Flash it's totally ok to load unsecure content...) (Flash uses around 25% CPU, while HTML5 uses 9% on

It seems like most solutions goes into a loop... Please help

Comment: Twitch enforces HTTPS on their end. So it redirects you to https, your app then redirects back to http, etc etc.

Comment: Disabling security is a terrible idea.

Comment: Any serious hacker could just buy a fraudulent certificate with ease anyway... CA system is broken

Comment: Workaround given in this SO post - [Since v38, Chrome extension cannot load from HTTP URLs anymore, workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285539/since-v38-chrome-extension-cannot-load-from-http-urls-anymore-workaround) might work for you too.