# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest using background pages - Chrome extension version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have used this page [Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest using background pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699615/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-using-background-pages) to create a simple extension but I get following errors.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

I used this sample extension then added the contents https://github.com/SimGus/chrome-extension-v3-starter

forground.js

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method: 'POST',
    action: 'xhttp',
    url: 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/search',
    data: 'q=something'
}, function (responseText) {
    console.log(responseText);
});
```

service-worker.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';

        xhttp.onload = function () {
            callback(xhttp.responseText);
        };
        xhttp.onerror = function () {
            // Do whatever you want on error. Don't forget to invoke the
            // callback to clean up the communication port.
            callback();
        };
        xhttp.open(method, request.url, true);
        if (method == 'POST') {
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        xhttp.send(request.data);
        return true; // prevents the callback from being called too early on return
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Chrome Extension v3 Starter",
    "description": "A minimal example of a chrome extension using manifest v3",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo/logo-16.png",
        "48": "logo/logo-48.png",
        "128": "logo/logo-128.png"
    },
    "options_page": "settings/settings.html",
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Chrome Addon v3 Starter",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "https://www.stackoverflow.com/search"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["foreground.js"],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Service worker doesn't have XMLHttpRequest. Use `fetch`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071/3959875).