# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecated

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, deprecated, chromium, synchronous

Today, I had to restart my browser due to some issue with an extension. What I found when I restarted it, was that my browser (Chromium) automatically updated to a new version that doesn't allow synchronous AJAX-requests anymore. Quote:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I need synchronous AJAX-requests for my node.js applications to work though, as they store and load data from disk through a server utilizing fopen. I found this to be a very simplistic and effective way of doing things, very handy in the creation of little hobby projects and editors... Is there a way to re-enable synchronous XMLHttpRequests in Chrome/Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has been edited.

**Short answer:**
They don't want sync on the *main* thread.

The solution is simple for new browsers that support threads/web workers:

```
var foo = new Worker("scriptWithSyncRequests.js")
```

Neither DOM nor global vairables aren't going to be visible within a worker but encapsulation of multiple synchronous requests is going to be really easy.

Alternative solution is to switch to async but to use browser [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) along with JSON.stringify as a medium. You might be able to mock localStorage if you allowed to do some IO.
http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Just for fun, there are alternative hacks if we want to restrict our self using only sync:

It is tempting to use setTimeout because one might think it is a good way to encapsulate synchronous requests together. Sadly, there is a gotcha. Async in javascript doesn't mean it gets to run in its own thread. Async is likely postponing the call, waiting for others to finish. Lucky for us there is light at the end of the tunnel because it is likely you can use xhttp.timeout along with xhttp.ontimeout to recover. See [Timeout XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523686/timeout-xmlhttprequest)
This means we can implement tiny version of a schedular that handles failed request and allocates time to try again or report error.

```
// The basic idea.
function runSchedular(s)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (s.ptr < callQueue.length) {
            // Handles rescheduling if needed by pushing the que.
            // Remember to set time for xhttp.timeout.
            // Use xhttp.ontimeout to set default return value for failure.
            // The pushed function might do something like: (in pesudo)
            // if !d1
            // d1 = get(http...?query);
            // if !d2
            // d2 = get(http...?query);
            // if (!d1) {pushQue tryAgainLater}
            // if (!d2) {pushQue tryAgainLater}
            // if (d1 && d2) {pushQue handleData}
            s = s.callQueue[s.ptr++](s);
        } else {
            // Clear the que when there is nothing more to do.
            s.ptr = 0;
            s.callQueue = [];
            // You could implement an idle counter and increase this value to free
            // CPU time.
            s.t = 200;
        }
        runSchedular(s);
    }, s.t);
}
```

Comment: *"For older browser support"* older browsers will continue to support sync requests, so there may not be much need for said alternative solutions. If browser supports workers, do x, else do y

Comment: @Keven B Looking at http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers, I think you are right on the part there is no need for them.

Comment: @Keven B As for the "y" part, if that means doing async requests by chaining then I for one would like to know about alternative solutions.

Comment: It's definitely nice to have alternatives, and they do make your answer better. I just wanted to note that they may not be needed in all cases. Nothing wrong with including them in the answer.

Comment: @Keven B These alternatives are definetely not the first choice! I will update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't "deprecated" mean that it's available, but won't be forever.  (I read elsewhere that it won't be going away for a number of years.)  If so, and this is for hobby projects, then perhaps you could use `async: false` for now as a quick way to get the job done?