# How to Cancel a Parse JavaScript Query

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to cancel the callbacks of a Parse JavaScript query? I occasionally experience a poor internet connection which allows the query to hang out there for quite a while. I'd like to be able to abort the query at a point of my choosing. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, you just get a promise you can use to wait but not cancel

Comment: wrap the query in an xhr request . then , set the time-out on that object and use the http/socket/protocol for your 'cancel'.... see accepted answer with 'xhr.timeOut'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523686/timeout-xmlhttprequest