# Does the browser have a max time limit for network requests?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, browser

When initiating a network request in the browser via `fetch` or `xmlhttprequest`, what happens if the network request takes a very long time? E.g. 20 minutes. Does the browser have a time limit after which it rejects requests? Is it possible to extend this?

I am thinking about a large file upload using a single network request to a server endpoint, but which might take a very long time over slow connections. Though I am only asking about browser behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523686/timeout-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: The browser will never terminate file upload requests as long as data is being transmitted, AFAIK.

Comment: @Kinglish I think that's for timing out in a shorter amount of time. I want requests to go longer.

Comment: @WaisKamal This would be very helpful if true

Answer (score 0):

Usually these values are set on the web server.

You may want to reach out to the Web Administrator and see if they can adjust the xmlhttprequest time out value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout

Additional Unsolicited Suggestion: For large uploads / big data, try to utilize Jumbo Frames if possible.